# Deleting specific documents from mongo in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

I want to delete about 5 documents from my DB in Java/Groovy but I am not able to do so. I have following code.

```
def deletedocuments() {
    for (int n = 0; n < documentNames.size(); n++) {
         dbConnection.getCollection(documentNames[n])**.remove**
    }

}
```

documentNames is a arraylist of collections that I would like to delete data from.  However, the 'remove' method is not available here. How do I do this?

Comment: Try `dbConnection.getCollection(collectionNames[n]).drop()`

Answer (score 0):

Just to formally add an answer ( already answered by Veeram):

Use this:

```
collectionNames().each{ String collectionName ->

       dbConnection."${collectionName}".drop();

}
```

Comment: I dont want to drop the collection, I want to delete data in them.  So 'drop' is not the choice here.

Comment: but your questions says "deleteing specific collections" do you mean "specific documents"?

Comment: you have to update your code as well and specify the name of the collection

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing like this

```
 for (int n = 0; n < documentNames.size(); n++) {
        DBCollection documentsToDelete = db.getCollection(documentNames[n]);
        documentsToDelete.remove()
    }
}
```

I haven't run the program yet, but it is not giving me any compile error

Comment: still you are trying to remove a collection not a document.